# Changing Chart Type using Morris.js

Tags: php, ajax, morris.js

I have a formatting problem with Morris.js. When I use a Bar Graph the format of the data is fine, but when I switch to a Line Graph the format is somewhat funny. The only problem is the Line Graph for Month the Daily and Yearly format is fine.

How can I fix the format on my Line Graph?

[Screen shot for Bar Graph (Month)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o9I7.png)
[Screen shot for Line Graph (Month)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZNwV.png)

AJAX Monthly Code:

```
$("#m-t-sales").click(function(){
    document.getElementById("total-sales").innerHTML = "";
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $("#d-t-sales").removeClass("active");
    $("#y-t-sales").removeClass("active");
    $.ajax ({
        url:"show_total_monthly_sales.php",
        method: "POST",
        success: function(branch_data){
            new Morris.Line({
                element: 'total-sales',
                data: JSON.parse(branch_data),
                xkey: 'month',
                ykeys: ['sales'],
                labels: ['Total Sales'],
                hideHover: 'auto'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
require_once "connect.php";

$data = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["branch"]);

$ar = array();

$sql = "SELECT MONTHNAME(date) AS date, SUM(sales) AS sales FROM tblSales GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $ar[] = array(
        'month' => $row['date'],
        'sales' => $row['sales']
    );
}
ob_clean();
echo json_encode($ar);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a problem of time values on x axis. Try with the option `parseTime: false`